# After viewing the picture. How can it be closed

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I want to be able to click on the view button and then it enlarges the picture I then want to be able to click on the page and the picture goes back to its normal size.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import { CardMedia } from '@mui/material';

export default function BasicModal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>View</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >

         <CardMedia 
            sx={{paddingTop: '100%'}}
            image="https://lorempokemon.fakerapi.it/pokemon"
            title="Image title"
        />
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What's the behaviour that is unexpected with this code? In addition to what you want to happen, please explain what is actually happening and how it's different from your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I think try to use useEffect. This is an example from w3schools. Here is the relevant page:
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp
It worked for my similar problem.

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs on the first render
  //And any time any dependency value changes
}, [open]);
```

It should render again at every time change `open` variable